# Android : Hello, Views > Google Map View Tuorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to complete the Android MapView tutorial @ www.developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

I think I've done the entire thing correctly but I'm getting an error message in Eclipse. I'm sure why. The problematic line of code is

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
```

I'm relatively new to Java but I've gone through the forums of different things and I really have no idea on this one. I've [attached][2] a screen shot of the development environment - hopefully it wont be anything too obvious or hard to fix either!

http://www.limedomains.com/files/download/34780?dirname=&file_name=hellogooglemaps.jpg

Cheers

Tom :)

** As requested heres the source code and the screenshot link is updated to something that works**

```
package com.example.hellogooglemaps;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay{

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
      return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
          super(defaultMarker);
          mContext = context;
        }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your screen shot is wayyy to small to read. I think you linked us to a thumbnail. Share the problem in plain ascii!

Comment: I imagine this is an easy answer, but with the tiny screenshot and no bug text, it is impossible to help.  In any case, as others have suggested, please just paste the error text in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the ArrayList inside the class, not outside, like this:

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is impossible to read.. please copy/paste what the logcat says...

For my personnal use, i use this code: List mapOverlays;